# multiple HABTM relationships for same tables - Cake 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 2 tables in my cakephp 3 app - **Items** and **Colors**. An Item can have multiple Primary Colors and Secondary Colors as well.
So, I have created 2 junction tables - *items_primary_colors* and *items_secondary_colors*.
Both have the same schema - *item_id* and *color_id* (Joining the Items and Colors tables)
I am not sure how to specify these relationships in TableModel and how to format the form data to save both types of colors.
My **ItemTable.php** code has -

```
$this->belongsToMany('Colors', [
    'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'color_id',
    'joinTable' => 'items_primary_colors'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('Colors', [
    'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'color_id',
    'joinTable' => 'items_secondary_colors'
]);
```

And, I am formatting the form data this way -

```
[primary_colors] => Array
(
    [_ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )
)

[secondary_colors] => Array
(
    [_ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

)
```

Its not working. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give the belongsToMany relationships different names. Try

```
$this->belongsToMany('PrimaryColors', [
    'className' => 'Colors',
    'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'color_id',
    'joinTable' => 'items_primary_colors'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('SecondaryColors', [
    'className' => 'Colors',
    'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'color_id',
    'joinTable' => 'items_secondary_colors'
]);
```